# Shazam with SoundCloud?

Tags: iphone, shazam

Is there a way to get Shazam to listen to music in SoundCloud or MixCloud while I am listening on headphones on my iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

You go into the Shazam app and you need to long press the Shazam logo until the "Auto-Shazam" words appear on the top of the circle. After that when you go back to your home page it will appear a red bar on top of your apps meaning that your Shazam will be listening to whatever song is going to be played.

EDIT: It works with headphones of course :)